# Can we divide both side by $r$ in polar equation?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, polar-coordinates

I was studying a *Coordinate Geometry*'s chapter especially dedicated to $\mathit circles$. There I found the equation of a circle with center $\mathcal {(r_1, \theta_1)}$ and radius $\pmb a$ in **polar coordinate system** is $a^2= r^2+ r_1^{2} -2rr_{1}\cos(\theta-\theta_1)$. So far I have understood how we got here. Then there was a *corollary* stating-

*Cor. 1.* If the circle passes through the pole `(which is the origin in rectangular coordinate system)` then $r_1=a$ and the equation of the circle becomes- $$a^2= r^2+ a^{2} -2ra\cos(\theta-\theta_1) \\ \implies r^2 =2ra\cos(\theta-\theta_1)  \\\implies  \bbox[yellow] { r=2a\cos(\theta-\theta_1)}$$
In the highlighted section above they divided both sides of the equation by $r$. As far as I know, you cannot divide both sides by $r$ if $r$ happens to be $ 0$. But graphing the equation $r=2a\cos\left(\theta\right)$ where $\theta_1$ is set to be $0$  in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fkumndekzo) shows that it infact passes through the pole where $r=0$ when $\theta=90^{\circ}$.

### *$\mathcal {My ~Question:}$*

So, is it legitimate to **divide both sides by $r$** while $r$  can be equal to $0$ in graph of the equation? **If so, why?** I see in some textbooks they keep it in the former form without dividing by $r$ but in most place they divide both sides by $r$.

Comment: Instead of "dividing", think "factoring".

Comment: From what I understand, the polar coordinates of the origin are sometimes left undefined. If we try to write $0$ in the form $(r,\theta)$, then $r$ must be $0$, but what is $\theta$? Some authors use the convention $\theta = 0$, but you can see from this that things get a little bit fiddly.

Comment: @Joe, maybe it refers to a point circle centered at the origin. _Not sure_.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking $r^2 =rk$ implies $r=k$ or $r=0$

so $r^2 =2ra\cos(\theta-\theta_1)$ implies $r =2a\cos(\theta-\theta_1)$ or $r=0$

but since  $\theta = \theta_1\pm \frac \pi2$ (or $\theta = \theta_1\pm 90^\circ$ if you are using degrees) also implies $r=0$, they may have felt adding $r=0$ explicitly was unnecessary

Comment: Doesn't $\pi$ corresponds to $180^\circ $ in degree measurement? Moreover how did we get the relation $\theta = \theta_1\pm \pi$ (or $\theta = \theta_1\pm 90^\circ$? `I'm actually a newbie in polar coordinates.`

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon You are correct - thank you - now edited

Comment: your answer seems promising but how did you get this relation $\theta = \theta_1\pm \frac \pi2$ ?

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon If you are working in radians $\cos(\frac \pi 2) = 0 = \cos(-\frac \pi 2)$ so if $\theta - \theta_1 = \pm \frac \pi 2 $ then $r=0$

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can say :

"either $r=0$ (first curve) or $r=2a \cos(...)$.

The "or" between equations corresponds to "union" for the associated curves ; therefore you make the union of a point (the origin) and the second curve (which happens to contain already the origin...).

Finally, nothing is changed...

Comment: Hi, @jeanmarie , Is there any online source where I can learn more about *The "or" between equations corresponds to "union" for the associated curves.* Moreover, I am currently dealing with lots of conic section problem, so is there any ROOM of SE where you help students?